# ezpublish: New siteaccess require user to login

Tags: ezpublish

I added fre siteacces to ezpublish (tried with 2014.05.0 and 2014.03.2) but it require user to login.With eng siteaccess it is working just as it should.

This is my config:

```
ezpublish:
    siteaccess:
        default_siteaccess: eng
        list: [eng, fre, apanel]
        groups:
            site_group: [eng, fre, apanel]
            backend_group: [apanel]
            frontend_group: [eng, fre]
        match:
            URIElement: '1'
    repositories:
      main: { engine: legacy, connection: my_connection }            
    system:
        site_group:
          repository: main
          var_dir: var/lla

        frontend_group:
            translation_siteaccesses: [eng, fre]
        eng:
            languages: [eng-GB]
        fre:
            languages: [fre-FR, eng-GB]
```

Any help :S?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a policy for the anonymous role to view content in this new siteaccess. You can do this in the admin interface by editing the Anonymous role and adding a new policy: Setup -> Roles & Policies -> Anonymous -> Edit.

Check out https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/5.x/Concepts-and-basics/Access-control for more details.